# How to delete the error cell in ipython interactive window?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ipython, jupyter

How can I delete an error cell while working in ipython interactive window?

```
In [1]: x = 5

In [2]: y = 10

In [3]: print(hello world)
  File "<ipython-input-3-6135c6da936c>", line 1
    print(hello world)
                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax


In [4]:
```

I want to delete the line 3. How can I do it? Or is there any way to make a correction in line 3 and rerun it?
The Reason I want to do this is that later I want to save my current session work in a python file. If I don't delete it or correct it then the error code, in this case, `print(hello world)` also gets saved in the python file. so I have to manually open that file and delete that line and then save it again.

Comment: Sounds like you should be using a jupyter notebook and not ipython. Another trick that i like to do before closing sessions in ipython is run the command `history` that prints out nicely every command i ran, without the output though, but easier to edit when copying into a file.

Answer (score 0):

Realize you are in an interactive window.  So there isn't really such an action of "deleting line 3".  It's in the past...  You should look at some of the ipython magic commands such as `%load`, `%edit`, `%history`, `%run`, and `%save`.  They are pretty awesome at re-executing and editing in ipython.

This is a good place to start:

https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html